# How to add Signed Apk Keystone in google-service.json

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I debug my apk in emulator or device it run perfectly. But when I build signed apk, and that apk won't work firebase login in real device.

How can I addbuild signed apk keystone into google-service.json

Please demonstrate with code. I don't know about goole-service.json and also signed apk keystone.

I just connect firbase ussing android assistance, and it's do automatically.
I create manually a keystone for signed apk name.jks
But how I can implement that key config in google-service.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to add SHA1 of Variant: release into firebase project then add new json file in app directory and generate signed apk you must be able to login with firebase.